# MySQL daemon failed to start

Tags: mysql, replication

MySQL won't restart when I try "service mysqld restart"because I'm using this part in `my.cnf`

```
master-host =  [private-IP-of-db01]
master-user = [replication-username]
master-password = [replication-password]
master-connect-retry = 60
```

when I comment out these parts! MySQL restarts fine. Why is that so? Also I have to include these lines in `my.cnf` because of master slave replication and I can't omit them out.

[image]

Comment: What is the content of your log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually master host information on the slave mysql server is stored in "master.info" file and maintained there. You may want to start mysql without adding the configuration to your "my.cnf" file, the only configuration you may want to add is a "server_id" , Once mysql is up and running, you should setup slave with 'change master command....'.

Comment: I do setup slave using master command but the problem is that when ever I close my putty terminals and start them again there is no more replication. Si I thought may be this is because I'm not adding these information in my.cnf

Comment: after giving 'change master command' i hope you are executing "START SLAVE", can u post the output from "show slave status\G"

Comment: yes i did start my slave and it works fine when I configure master slave for the first time! everything replicates fine the problem starts when I close putty terminals and start them again slave status shows that replication is fine but actually nothing is being replicated

Comment: the only db you are replicating is 'aqsacheck' , i hope you have some activity going on in that database. you can try the "show master status" and check if its not ignored.

Comment: Ok I made a huge mistake , I was trying to replicate db's that were not even mentioned in my master and slave my.cnf file